# Unexpected large empty space on rdlc report

Tags: visual-studio, report, rdlc

I'm trying to design a report on rdlc that contains many tables, matrix and some textboxes. Even if i designed the report without any large empty spaces as you can see in the screenshot below.

[image: Report Designer]

When i 'm trying to run this report the result that been produced contains many empty spaces between the tables and textboxes. In the screenshot below you can see the empty spaces as i described above.

[image]
I tried to set the width of tables' columns to static and give a default value. I cannot find why these empty spaces been produced. I have also tried the subreport solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Rectangle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd239352.aspx) as a container for other controls.

I think you can:

1. use a `Rectangle` for `Table1`, `Table2`, `Table3`
2. use another `Rectangle` for `Matrix1`
3. use another `Rectangle` for all `TextBox` on the left side of the page

You can learn more about rendering behaviors on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255244.aspx).